# How to send a dynamic response from a TaskExecutor with a REST API in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, rest

I want to create a REST API in a Spring Boot project. The business logic is very simple like a counter that need to increase at every 10 seconds until it hits 5 minutes. This will be the task for a TaskExecutor. Until now everything is ok, but I need to show this progress to the client. So the REST API should send this progress as a response.

I will do something like that:

So the client should receive 10 seconds, 20 seconds, ... until 5 minutes. But how can I send this dynamic response with a REST API? Can I do that on the /execute REST API that execute the task and get that progress or should I have 2 REST API, one /execute and another /get-progress? Thank you!

Comment: As the background thread progresses, it will need to occasionally update a thread safe variable that is accessible externally from the thread.  The simplest approach would be for the Map to include the variable (such as an `AtomicInteger`) as part of the Map value.  The variable is injected into  `SimpleTask`, and the variable is updated on each iteration of the loop.  A request to get the task progress returns the variable value.

Comment: @AndrewS So, instead of `Map<String, Future<?>>` to have `Map<String, AtomicInteger>`, right? But I need to keep the future because I need to have the option to cancel a task and I do that based on the future.

Comment: The Map value could be a composite that holds the `Future` and the `AomticInteger`.

Comment: Can I do that with only one request /execute to execute the task and get the progress or should I have 2 API, /execute to execute the task, and another one /get-progress to show the progress at a specific time?

Comment: Separate requests - one to start the long running task (which returns the task ID), and another to get the progress (or result when ready) based on the task ID.  The client periodically make a REST call (polling) to get the progress.  The question was about RESTful, but alternatively, the service could publish a message with the progress/result, and the client subscribes to the message (pub/sub).